# Why different object reference of shared object using Import and GetExportedValue in MEF?

Tags: c#, prism, mef, prism-5

I have an object as shown below.

```
[Serializable()]
[Export(typeof(IRuleFile))]    
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class RuleFile : NotifyPropertyChanged, IRuleFile { }
```

Using `[ImportConstructor]` or `[Import]`, same object reference is returned.

But by using programmatic approach the object returned is different although it should be singleton, why?

```
var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
var exportedObj = container.GetExportedValue<IRuleFile>();
```

**ADDED**

I have two view model in my solution, below i am showing only one but at the `[ImportConstructor]` object remain same but upon using `GetExportedValue` i get a new instance and constructor is invoking again.

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public partial class RuleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public RuleViewModel(IRuleFile ruleFile)
    {
        RuleFile = ruleFile; // here the object is fine            
    }

    // this method triggers at the time of loading rule file
    public void LoadRuleState()
    {
        var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        // at this point contructor triggers again in my case
        var exportedObj = container.GetExportedValue<IRuleFile>(); 

        // my intend is to replace the object back in the container after deserialization.
        RuleFile = SerializationHelper.DeserializeFromFile<RuleFile>(Constants.RuleDefinitionPath);
        container.ComposeExportedValue<IRuleFile>(RuleFile);
    }
}
```

My actual intend is to replace the object back in the MEF container after deserialization so that object remain the same.

Comment: You mean that exportedObj is different than the instances you got from [Import] ? Or using GetExportedValue several times results in different instances ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; I added an export on a class with an ImportingConstructor for IRuleFile and composed it, but IRuleFile's constructor was invoked only once and all instances were the same as exportedObj. Please add a complete case to reproduce this.

Comment: Yes in my case the constructor is firing twice, I have added a new section with shorten example from my solution above.

Comment: I'd say your constructor is firing twice because you are creating two objects explicitely: first using GetExportedValue, then by deserializing it. I also don't believe the `// at this point contructor triggers again in my case` is correct, it's probably at the line where a new object is being created by deserializing it. All in all, your question is invalid - it should actually be 'How do I put a deserialized object in a CompositionContainer' or so, at least I have the impression that is what you really want.

Comment: I know the constructor will be fired upon deserilization to form the object back but it is firing on this statement `var exportedObj = container.GetExportedValue<IRuleFile>();` itself. Same behavior even if i comment last two lines of deserialization code.

Comment: @stijn, You are right, for that i had already raised the question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595772/how-to-exchange-replace-the-shared-singleton-object-in-mef-container, but didn't get any answer so i am trying figure out the solution on my own by breaking the problem into chunks. First i am trying to retrieve the object then i ll try to destroy and re add it back in the container after deserialization.

Comment: `it is firing on this statement` as said, I cannot reproduce this. Are you *sure* that if you take the minimal code above, remove the serialization stuff, paste it in a new empty project, the constructor is invoked twice?

Comment: @stijn, I have shared the example minimal code with the said issue at this location: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxVaSk3iX4mSNjNUaDM5dkF1MzA&usp=sharing. Please point me what is wrong in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason two instances are being created is that your code uses two different `AssemblyCatalog` and `CompositionContainer` instances, and those are completely independent. So when using `Import` and the likes, MEF uses the global container instance created in the bootstrapper. However in LoadRuleState you create a new container, which is empty and doesn't know about existing instances of any object, and hence creates a new RuleFile when you ask for it.

The usual trick when you want to work with the CompositionContainer outside of the bootstrapper is to simply add it to itself:

```
public class MefMuiBootstrapper : MefBootstrapper
{
  protected override void ConfigureContainer()
  {
    base.ConfigureContainer();
    Container.ComposeExportedValue( Container );
  }
}
```

and then you can Import it like any other Export:

```
[Export]
public class ViewModel
{
  private readonly CompositionContainer container;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public ViewModel( CompositionContainer container )
  {
    this.container = container;
  }

  public void Load()
  {
    var exportedObj = container.GetExportedValue<IRuleFile>();
  }
}
```

Comment: @stijin, I used the above approach but i am getting Container as null. The only difference is that i am using property `[Import]` instead of `[ImportingConstructor]` due to one constraint of object structure. Also i am using the Container object after object initialization and not before that. What could be the reason for it?

Comment: If it works ok with ImportingConstructor (did you try that? eventually just in a simple class for testing), it should also work with Import, but only after the MEF composition completes. You can know when that is by deriving from IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.ipartimportssatisfiednotification%28v=vs.110%29.aspx